# Entity Framework Core 2 One to Many created with Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I hope you can help me with this problem:

I have an old database, with two tables in it:

- Datensatz
- Kampagnendaten

One Datensatz can have 0 to many Kampagnendaten.  So far nothing special, but:

Datensatz has the fields:
Id
Name

Kampagnendaten has the fields:
Id
Idds
Name
Value

Idds is the field that holds the Id of the Datensatz, but this field is not defined as a foreign key in the database.

I let EF Core reverse engineer my models and then I modified the created DatabaseContext:

Datensatz:

```
entity.HasMany<KampagnenDaten>(d => d.KampagnenDatenList).WithOne().HasForeignKey(k => k.Idds);
```

Kampagnendaten:

```
entity.HasOne<Datensatz>().WithMany(d => d.KampagnenDatenList).HasForeignKey(k => k.Idds).HasPrincipalKey(d => d.Id);
```

I also modified the DatensatzModel:

```
List<KampagnenDaten> KampagnenDaten { get; set; }
```

Now when I execute the following:

```
context.Datensatz.Include(d => d.KampagnenDatenList).FirstOrDefault<Datensatz>(d => d.Id == id);
```

I get a Datensatz which has an array of KampagnenDaten which only includes one element.

How can I get all KampagnenDaten for the Datensatz? (Yes Datensatz has 11 KampagnenDaten in the KampagnenDaten table).

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns only 1 record if it finds a match in your lambda expression. Try to use `where` clause

Comment: in DatensatzModel, the linked KampagnenData are called `KampagnenDaten`, but in your request you wrote `d => d.KampagnenDatenList` . Is there a typo here ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var datensatz = context.Datensatz.Include(d => d.KampagnenDatenList).FirstOrDefault<Datensatz>(d => d.Id == id);
var datensatzId = datensatz.Id;

// what you want. You can add includes if you need.
var kdList = context.KampagnenDaten.Where(k => k.Idds == datensatzId).ToList();
```

Comment: I understand the same also i thought tha same answer

Comment: Yes this works, but not exactly what I want:  I want to be able to return the Datensatz object as json containing all it's related Kampagnendaten.  Your example works well if you only get one Datensatz, but if you get a list of Datensatz then you have to go thru it and add all the KampangenDaten to each Datensatz, which would make this very slow.

Comment: @Pac0 Yes it is a one to many relationship One Datensatz can have 0 to x KampagnenDaten and each KampagnenDaten has exactly one Datensatz.

Comment: @Pac0 No there are 11 entries in KampagnenDaten with the Id of the Datensatz in KampagnenDaten.Idds.  If I query the Database with the Query that is generated by EntityFramework I do get all 11 Entries but they never show up in the Datensatz Object.  At first I thought it was the FirstOrDefault in the query but that does not make a difference.

Comment: @PWFraley Can you change the definition of KampagnenDatenList? It should be : `public virtual ICollection<KampagnenDaten> KampagnenDatenList{ get; set; }` IMO. (and in the constructor, don't forget to initialize it to a `new List<KampagnenDaten>()`)

Comment: Solved: It was a combination of two things:
1. Removed the reverse declaration from KapagnenDaten (11 Elements came but 11 times the same element)
2. Removed the Key declaration in KampagnenDaten (now all 11 elements are there)

Comment: @PWFraley : thanks for feedback. You can post an answer to your own question describing the correct syntax and accept it !